# NameError in Django model? Why Cant I reference something within a model?

Tags: django, django-models, python-2.7

For some reason I can't get this model to get any relationship with each other? And Aptana is giving me the red line and error saying Test1 and Test2 are undefined Variables... At first I thought its just aptana messing up so i decided to syncdb it but its actually giving me errors saying NameError: name Test1 is not defined? what could be the reason? thanks in advance!

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from userena.models import UserenaBaseProfile

class MyProfile(UserenaBaseProfile):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True, verbose_name=_('User'), related_name='my_profile')
    favourite_snack = models.CharField(_('favourite snack'), max_length=5)
    test1 = models.ManyToManyField(Test1)

class Test1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    test2 = models.OneToOneField(Test2)

class Test2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the order in which the classes are defined.  Python interpreter does not do a forward lookup
This should fix your issue.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from userena.models import UserenaBaseProfile

class Test2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Test1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    test2 = models.OneToOneField(Test2)

class MyProfile(UserenaBaseProfile):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True, verbose_name=_('User'), related_name='my_profile')
    favourite_snack = models.CharField(_('favourite snack'), max_length=5)
    test1 = models.ManyToManyField(Test1)
```

Comment: That was simple... Thanks! But now it comes to my next question.. why does the following work? from django.db import models

class T1(models.Model):
    t2 = models.ForeignKey(T2)

class T2(models.Model):
    t1 = models.ForeignKey(T1)

Comment: python is an interpreted language, and the interpreter goes line by line. By the time test1 is referenced, it does not have the capability to do a forward lookup. hence throws the error

Answer (score 4):

You are referencing the model before it was created actually that is why you are having `undefined` error, Use Model name as string instead of actual model:

```
models.OneToOneField('Test2')
```

As stated [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#module-django.db.models.fields.related):

> If you need to create a relationship on a model that has not yet been defined, you can use the name of the model, rather than the model object itself

Other approach would be to reorder the models in your file according to in what order they are referenced as `karthikr` mentioned.

Comment: i wanted to add one to your answer since i cant accept both answers but since im new no reputation cant even vote one...

Comment: @user2242246 no problem at all.The important thing is that it helped you.